# Authenticate on API as AD B2C anonymous

Tags: c#, azure, devops, azure-ad-b2c

Im creating a custom policy on azure AD B2C for signup, so i need when the users are registering, check if the domain is already registered, i'm trying to do this with a Azure function but i don't know how to authenticate in this function, i don't like to leave this azure function anonymous because anyone can access and know if a company is registered or not on my app

any idea or useful doc? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To learn about how to protect Azure functions, refer to [Microsoft docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#http-auth). Scroll to **Authorization level** header in the page.

- In your case, you could set `function` as authorization level. You will be able to copy the function key for the azure function from azure portal.
- Create a policy key in Azure AD B2C with your copied policy key value (Policy key reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/policy-keys-overview?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)).
- Call the endpoint from your custom policies with the policy key.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="RestApi-DummyAzureFunctionCall">
    <DisplayName>DummyAzureFunctionCall</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{Settings:FunctionsAppUrl}/api/company?name={companyName}</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ApiKeyHeader</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="x-functions-key" StorageReferenceId="{Settings:FunctionsAppApiKeyName}" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="comapanyName" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isRegistered" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

- Replace `{Settings:FunctionsAppApiKeyName}` with your policy key name from Azure AD B2C.